# Perl Excel preview problem in Outlook

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

I am generating Excel  report in Perl.

I am using the Formula in the cell, it's working fine, but in Outlook when I see through preview file, the cell is showing something like `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Format=HASH(0x87d6d04)` instead of total.

I am using simple forumulas only, like `=sum(B1:B10)`  or `=sum(A1,B2)`.

How to fix this?

> [image: Blockquote]

outlook excel preview

Comment: Could you show us the Perl code you've written? Your printing a hashref there instead of its contents.

Comment: $worksheet->write($excel_serial_no,4,"=SUM(F${sum_excel_serial_no_2},G${sum_excel_serial_no_2})", $format05,$font );

Comment: give some suggestion, problem yet not fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use the `write_formula` method rather than the plain write one.

For example,

```
$worksheet->write_formula(1, 0, '=SIN(B1:B10)');
```

From the documentation on CPAN for [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#write_formula%28%24row,_%24column,_%24formula,_%24format,_%24value%29)

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
$worksheet->write(..., $format05,$font );
```

You have an unnecessary trailing `$font`at the end of that method call which is being passed to `write_formula()` (via `write()`) as an optional result for the formula.

That is what is showing up as the formula result in Outlook.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use write() or write_formula(). The problem is that you have an extra format object called $font at the end of the method call. You need to remove that.

Comment: that contain the cell border/and few design stuff

Comment: Then that information should be in $format05. You cannot specify 2 formats in a write method like that.

Comment: Unknown defined name MTD in formula

Comment: MTD is not one of the supported functions listed in the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel documentation.